# Compare 2 datetime in Apex batch class

Tags: apex, soql, batch, datetime

I have below query where i need to compare datetime custom field with system.now.
Currently my timezone  is australia/sydney,which i need to consider,

I tried many combinations but getting Invalid Date/Time error

```
    String  now = Datetime.now().format();
    string query = 'select id,name,Start_Date__c from Notification__c where Start_Date__c >:'+now;
    system.debug('query>>'+query);
    return database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're dramatically overcomplicating this code. You do not need Dynamic SOQL at all. Just do

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c 
    FROM Notification__c 
    WHERE Start_Date__c >:DateTime.now()
]);
```

You can do this because `getQueryLocator()` [accepts a static query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_getQueryLocator). Using an [Apex expression binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) means that your code is not responsible for formatting values; the system does it for you.

Comment: there are 2 things first is datetime.now() is taking GMT time and my start_date is in Australia time zone and second i want to run this batch every min which will pick the record start date of next five min and it will perform the operation on those records.Please suggest

Comment: user timezone is australia/sydeny

Comment: Salesforce stores all date time values in UTC. It should make no difference what time zone the user is in.

Comment: The point here is because you use a binding Salesforce still has a Datetime value that it knows how to apply appropriately in the SOQL directly (it is rendering of a Datetime that converts it to the contextual user's timezone, not the Datetime value itself which is internally a UTC value).

Comment: BTW running the batch every minute may not function correctly since it may take more than a minute to queue, start, execute and finish any one instance of the batch. All async processing is controlled by the platform and scheduled apex is purely guaranteed not to be executed until the requested date and time but may be executed significantly after that date and time (up to 15 minutes later in extreme cases) since the platform is a multitenanted one and async processing is lower priority compared with asynchronous processing.